# Nested List to JSON in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, recursion

I am working on code that will take n-deep nested Lists and convert to JSON.

Running into a strange issue.

**Plunk:**

https://plnkr.co/edit/gHCoVakRPREYq6IBAGrQ?p=preview

**HTML:**

```
<div class="dd" name="category-nestable" id="nestable">
  <ol class="dd-list">
    <li class="dd-item" data-type="section" data-id="42" id="42">
      <div class="dd-handle">
        <span style="font-weight: bold" >Company</span>
      </div>
      <ol class="dd-list">
        <li class="dd-item" data-type="section" data-id="43" id="43">
          <div class="dd-handle">
            <span style="font-weight: bold" >Group</span>
          </div>
          <ol class="dd-list">
            <li class="dd-item" data-type="section" data-id="45" id="45">
              <div class="dd-handle">
                <span style="font-weight: bold" >SubGroup</span>
              </div>
              <ol class="dd-list">
                <li class="dd-item" data-type="section" data-id="45" id="45">
                  <div class="dd-handle">
                    <span style="font-weight: bold" >Sub-sub-Group</span>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ol>
            </li>
          </ol>
        </li>
      </ol>
      </li>
      <li class="dd-item" data-type="section" data-id="44" id="44">
        <div class="dd-handle">
          <span style="font-weight: bold" >User</span>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function newSaveCategories() {
    var nestableSections = $("#nestable>ol>li");
    var categories = newBuildCategories(nestableSections);
    var json = JSON.stringify(categories, null, 2);
    alert(json);
}

function newBuildCategories(categoriesRead) {
    var categories = [];

    categoriesRead.each(function() {
        var category = {};
        category.CategoryId = $(this).attr('data-id');
        category.CategoryName = $(this).find(".dd-handle").first().text().trim();
        category.SubCategories = newBuildCategories($(this).find('.dd-list').find('.dd-item'));
        categories.push(category);
    });      
    return categories;
}
```

**Bug:**

[image]

Comment: So if we inspected ` var categories = newBuildCategories(nestableSections);` we'd expect to see an array with two members:` [{CategoryName: 'Company' ... }, {CategoryName: 'User' ...}]`
When I download your plunk, change `alert` to `console.log`, click `Save`, open the developer console in Chromium, I see this very result.

Comment: You can see `...` in alert box, check in console. It shows every thing. You  need to change you nested function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to use `children` instead of `find`.

`find` matches all descendants, no matter how deep. `children` only matches immediate children. Your current code is grabbing grandchildren and treating them as children.

Comment: This resolved the issue, the duplicates were coming from find, thank you.